# Flickr style image grid

Tags: views, 7, media

I want to display a grid of pure image fields (no text). I would like for every image on each row to have the same height (not every row must have the same height) and the total width of every row to be the same as their container. Just like images appear on Flickr. Is there a module to do this? (I am using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to generate the grid.)

Comment: Thanks for the `-1` without giving any insight on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is the desktop Flickr site and not mobile (mobile the galleries are all same height and width as far as I've seen) but either way you can do this in your image styles and CSS.

You would want to make your view output in the image style that you make to constrain the height and/or width.

You can find tutorials on Drupal.org or online like this one: https://www.drupal.org/node/2152441 that will help get started. After that you would use custom CSS to make it look how you want.

Note: I know this is a vague answer but the question was a little vague so maybe it will help, maybe it won't?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the image field in views and add a CSS class to the field. Then set the height and or width in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Look into theme'ing your view...

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Cfc11_sb5M

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jusitified Grid](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/), which is a jQuery plug-in for achieving this kind of layout.